# different hadoop type files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop generally supports these file formats: SequenceFile, TFile and Avro.

1. Are there any other major formats that it supports?
2. How about images? Are they stored using the same file formats? Do they have to be indexed/queried in a different way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

MapFile is a SortedSequnceFile with an index to permit look ups by key. Images can be stored as-is or in a SequenceFile/MapFile for processing.